# CSS pseudo element gets rebuilt in bootstrap tabs

Tags: css, bootstrap-4

I am adding a ::before pseudo element to list item elements that live within a Bootstrap Tab.

The pseudo element has a css animation that I can trigger by toggling the class.

Everything works, however, when I move between tabs, the css animation is being triggered.
I inspected the DOM and notices that everything I switch tabs, the pseudo elements get added or removed.

This results in the css animation being played every-time the tab with the list is opened. I don't want this to happen.

I don't understand why this is happening. Shouldn't the CSS be applied to the list items even when the tab they are in is not visible?
How can I stop the CSS animation from playing when opening the tab?

```css
.myList {
  list-style: none;
}

.myList .state-in {
  position: relative;
}

.state-in::before {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  left: -30px;
  top: 1px;
  width: calc(100% + 40px);
  height: 24px;
  animation: takeInFade 1s ease-in-out;
}

@keyframes takeInFade {
  0% { background-color: transparent; }
  30% { background-color: #466d2a; }
  100% { background-color: transparent; }
}

@keyframes takeOutFade {
  0% { background-color: transparent; }
  30% { background-color: #7b2d2a; }
  100% { background-color: transparent; }
}
```

```html
<html>
  <head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" crossorigin="anonymous">
  
  
  </head>
  <body>
    
    <ul class="nav nav-tabs" id="myTab" role="tablist">
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link active" id="home-tab" data-toggle="tab" href="#home" role="tab" aria-controls="home" aria-selected="true">Tab One</a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link" id="profile-tab" data-toggle="tab" href="#profile" role="tab" aria-controls="profile" aria-selected="false">Tab Two</a>
      </li>
    </ul>
    <div class="tab-content" id="myTabContent">
      <div class="tab-pane fade show active" id="home" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="home-tab">
        <ul class="myList">
          <li class="state-in">Item One</li>
          <li class="state-in">Item Two</li>
          <li class="state-in">Item Three</li>
        </ul>
      </div>
      <div class="tab-pane fade" id="profile" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="profile-tab">
        Tab Two Content
      </div>
    </div>
    
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-q8i/X+965DzO0rT7abK41JStQIAqVgRVzpbzo5smXKp4YfRvH+8abtTE1Pi6jizo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JjSmVgyd0p3pXB1rRibZUAYoIIy6OrQ6VrjIEaFf/nJGzIxFDsf4x0xIM+B07jRM" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated! TIA!

Comment: what you want to . can you please explain

Comment: I think tab.js indeed rebuilds HTML on .show(), it makes height, transitions, and all sort of things easier to calculate as JS cannot get the height (for example) of an element  if it's hidden. Checkout the way tab.js works in bootstrap. Check out https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/blob/master/js/src/tab.js and the related events to see how it works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One *hacky* way is to change the behavior of the bootstrap tab and instead of toggling the `display` property you can change the position to absolute and opacity to 0.

Here is the relevant part of the code

```
.tab-content>.tab-pane {
    display: block!important;
    position:absolute;
    opacity:0;
}
.tab-content>.active {
    display: block;
    opacity:1;
    position:relative;
}
```

Full code:

```css
.myList {
  list-style: none;
}

.myList .state-in {
  position: relative;
}

.state-in::before {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  left: -30px;
  top: 1px;
  right:0;
  height: 24px;
  animation: takeInFade 1s ease-in-out;
}

@keyframes takeInFade {
  0% { background-color: transparent; }
  30% { background-color: #466d2a; }
  100% { background-color: transparent; }
}

@keyframes takeOutFade {
  0% { background-color: transparent; }
  30% { background-color: #7b2d2a; }
  100% { background-color: transparent; }
}


/**/
.tab-content>.tab-pane {
    display: block!important;
    position:absolute;
    opacity:0;
}
.tab-content>.active {
    display: block;
    opacity:1;
    position:relative;
}
/**/
```

```html
<html>
  <head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" crossorigin="anonymous">
  
  
  </head>
  <body>
    
    <ul class="nav nav-tabs" id="myTab" role="tablist">
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link active" id="home-tab" data-toggle="tab" href="#home" role="tab" aria-controls="home" aria-selected="true">Tab One</a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link" id="profile-tab" data-toggle="tab" href="#profile" role="tab" aria-controls="profile" aria-selected="false">Tab Two</a>
      </li>
    </ul>
    <div class="tab-content" id="myTabContent">
      <div class="tab-pane fade show active" id="home" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="home-tab">
        <ul class="myList">
          <li class="state-in">Item One</li>
          <li class="state-in">Item Two</li>
          <li class="state-in">Item Three</li>
        </ul>
      </div>
      <div class="tab-pane fade" id="profile" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="profile-tab">
        Tab Two Content
      </div>
    </div>
    
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-q8i/X+965DzO0rT7abK41JStQIAqVgRVzpbzo5smXKp4YfRvH+8abtTE1Pi6jizo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JjSmVgyd0p3pXB1rRibZUAYoIIy6OrQ6VrjIEaFf/nJGzIxFDsf4x0xIM+B07jRM" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: You are right, it is a bit hacky but works perfectly! thanks!